# Comparing 2 dates to see if the current date is passed - React/Momentjs

Tags: reactjs, datetime, momentjs

I'm currently tying to compare 2 dates (and time): the date limit my action has to be completed and the current date.

I receive the date and time in this format: `2017-05-29T15:30:17.983Z`.

I then try to compare the 2 dates using this function:

```
function checkExceedLimit (props) {
    exceedLimit = 0;
    props.items.map((item) => {
        var dateLimit = moment(item.limit)
        var now = moment()
        if (item.limit != null || item != ' ' && now > dateLimit) {
            exceedLimit++;
            console.log(now)
            console.log(dateLimit)
        }
    })
}
```

Basically I want to compare the `limit` from each item and add +1 to exceedLimit when the current date is passed. Yet it returns +1 for each limit even though not all of them are passed.

Thank you for your help

Comment: moment has methods for this. LIke `isBefore` or `isAfter`. This should help you I think

Comment: Yeah I saw those methods but they didn't work when I tried them. Am I writing this correctly? `moment(dateLimit).isAfter())` ?

Comment: `moment('2010-10-20').isBefore('2010-12-31', 'year');` this is an example from the docs.

Comment: @petithomme no, you have to do `now.isAfter(dateLimit)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) and [`isAfter`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/), in your case you can do:

```js
if (item.limit != null || item != ' ' && now.isAfter(dateLimit) ) {
```

Comment: Used the same logic in my code and it worked. Just add parentheses to separate the `||` from the `&&` statement to change priority.
`if ((item.limit != null || item != ' ') && now.isAfter(dateLimit) ) {`
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should proper create your instance of moment.

Like this:
`moment("2017-05-29T15:30:17.983Z", 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ')`

You can check this link for more details: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

And then you can compare date using the moment's API methods on https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

So your code should look like this:

```js
function checkExceedLimit (props) {
  exceedLimit = 0;
  props.items.map((item) => {
    const dateLimit = moment(item.limit, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ');
    const now = moment()
    if (dateLimit.isValid() && now.isAfter(dateLimit)) {
        exceedLimit++;
        console.log(now.toString())
        console.log(dateLimit.toString())
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Great idea using the `isValid()` function in the if statement, I didn't think of that. For creating the dateLimit variable, I don't think you have to specify the format since both values are in momentjs. I'll add the isValid() function to my code. Thanks.

Comment: Once you said that the time is given in moment, I do agree with you that you don't need format it and not even create a moment. I've suggested that because I understood it was a string, once you specified the date format and put item.limit into a moment.

Comment: Oh I understand. Yeah `item.limit` was already formatted in my situation.